# Mount TV on Slate Tile accent wall without studs?

Tags: walls, ceramic-tile, television

How could I mount a tv on a slate tile accent wall. I don't think there are studs behind the tile, it is a hollow space. Another problem is my wall mount only has 2 holes to bolt to the wall.

Wall in question: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLF7E.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you think there are any studs?  The wall has to be supported by something.

Comment: Maybe, at least some sort of frame. The electrical box in the picture seems to be attached to cement or something on the inside. The fake fireplace goes back into the wall and there dont appear to be any wood, just more cement. The whole tile wall seems tacked on top of the normal wall

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture or two of the situation might help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.